# free() function in c on a struct generates a breakpoint without any error code

Tags: c, struct, linked-list, malloc, free

I'm trying to create a linked list of users in a social network in c. I have 2 modules:

1. User - a struct which contains a username (char), number of friends(int) and a linked list of friends (each block in the list contains a name and a pointer to next friend of the User).the User module has methods to add a friend to the list and to remove.

   2.Social network - general module to organize users. it contains a linked list of Users.the methods here control the users. It adds friends as part of add relationship function. it calls to the user methods and manages the users as part of the encapsulation rules.

I use malloc for the structs and chars. I eventually use free on those mallocs at the end of the program using functions such as Network_delete() and UserDelete(..)
I encounter an error while calling to free in Network_delete() function (breakpoint with no error code - not even heap related) and I can't figure out the issue. I use well-defined rules of the use of malloc but maybe I'm wrong in the assignment. 
comment: def.h contains the Result enum used in the modules.
the modules:
User.h

```
#ifndef _USER_H_
#define _USER_H_
#include "defs.h"
typedef struct LINKED_LIST* L_list;
typedef struct user_t *PUser;
PUser User_Create(char* name);
void User_Delete(PUser pUser);
Result User_addFriend(PUser pUser, char* name);
Result User_removeFriend(PUser pUser, char* name);
char* User_getName(PUser pUser);
L_list User_getFriendsList(PUser pUser);
int User_getFriendsNum(PUser pUser);
#endif /* _USER_H_ */
```

User.c

```
    #include "User.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

// linked list 
typedef struct LINKED_LIST {
    char* name;
    struct LINKED_LIST* pNext;
}L_L;
// user struct- include the user name,number of his friends and a list of his friends
typedef struct user_t
{
    char* name;
    L_list friends_list;
    int friends_num;
}USER;
// user creator
PUser User_Create(char* name)
{
    if (!name) return NULL;
    PUser pUser;
    pUser = (PUser)malloc(sizeof(USER));
    if (pUser == NULL) return NULL;
    if(!(pUser->name = (char*)malloc(1 +strlen(name)))) {
        free(pUser);
        return NULL;
    }
    pUser->friends_list = NULL;
    pUser->friends_num = 0;
    strcpy(pUser->name, name);
    return pUser;
}
// user destructor-delete the user and his friends list
void User_Delete(PUser pUser)
{
    if (!pUser) return;
    L_list current = pUser->friends_list;
    L_list to_delete = current;
    while (current)
    {
        current = current->pNext;
        free(to_delete->name);
        free(to_delete);
    }
    pUser->friends_list = NULL;
    free(pUser->name);
    free(pUser);
}
//add new friend to the friends list
Result User_addFriend(PUser pUser, char* name)
{
    if (!pUser||!name) return FAILURE;
    L_list current = pUser->friends_list;
    while (current)
    {
        if (strcmp(name, current->name)==0)
        {
            return FAILURE;
        }
        current = current->pNext;
    }
    L_list new_list_element = (L_list)malloc(sizeof(L_L));
    if (!new_list_element) return FAILURE;
    if (!(new_list_element->name = (char*)malloc(1 + strlen(name)))) {
        free(new_list_element);
        return FAILURE;
    }
    strcpy( new_list_element->name ,name);
    new_list_element->pNext = pUser->friends_list;
    pUser->friends_list = new_list_element;
    pUser->friends_num++;
    return SUCCESS;
}
//remove friends from the friends list
Result User_removeFriend(PUser pUser, char* name)
{
    if (!pUser || !name) return FAILURE;
    L_list current = pUser->friends_list;
    L_list before_current = pUser->friends_list;
    while (current)
    {
        if (strcmp(current->name, name) == 0)
        {
            before_current->pNext = current->pNext;
            free(current->name);
            free(current);
            pUser->friends_num--;
            return SUCCESS;
        }
        before_current = current;
        current = current->pNext;
    }
    return FAILURE;
}
//get the user name
char* User_getName(PUser pUser)
{
    if (!pUser) return NULL;
    return pUser->name;
}
//get the first friend on the list
L_list User_getFriendsList(PUser pUser)
{
    if (!pUser) return NULL;
    return pUser->friends_list;
}
//get the user number of frinds 
int User_getFriendsNum(PUser pUser)
{
    if (!pUser) return 0;
    return pUser->friends_num;
}
}
```

Socialnetwork.h

```
    #ifndef _SOCIAL_NETWORK_H_
#define _SOCIAL_NETWORK_H_
#include "User.h"
typedef struct LINKED_LIST_SN* social_network_elem;// a list for social network
Result Network_addUser(char* member_invite, char* new_member);
Result Network_addRelationship(char* member1, char* member2);
Result Network_removeRelationship(char* member1, char* member2);
void Network_delete();
#endif /* _SOCIAL_NETWORK_H_ */
```

Socialnetwork.c

```
    #include "SocialNetwork.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "User.h"
typedef struct LINKED_LIST_SN {
    PUser pUser;
    struct LINKED_LIST_SN* pNext;
}S_N_L;

social_network_elem pSocial_network;
//adding new user to the network
Result Network_addUser(char* member_invite, char* new_member)
{
    if (!member_invite && !new_member) return FAILURE;//bad input
    if (!new_member&&(pSocial_network!=NULL)) return FAILURE;
    if (!member_invite&&new_member)//first member
    {
        pSocial_network = (social_network_elem)malloc(sizeof(S_N_L));
        if (!pSocial_network) return FAILURE;
        pSocial_network->pUser = User_Create(new_member);
        pSocial_network->pNext = NULL;
        return SUCCESS;
    }
    social_network_elem current = pSocial_network;
    PUser pMember_invite=NULL;
    while (current)
    {
        if (strcmp(new_member, User_getName(current->pUser)) == 0)//new_member already in social network
        {
            return FAILURE;
        }
        if (strcmp(member_invite, User_getName(current->pUser)) == 0)//apdating  pointer to the member who invited
        {
            pMember_invite = current->pUser;
        }
        current = current->pNext;
    }
    if (!pMember_invite) return FAILURE; //no inviting member found in network
    social_network_elem pNew_social_network_elem;
    pNew_social_network_elem = (social_network_elem)malloc(sizeof(S_N_L));
    if (!pNew_social_network_elem) return FAILURE;
    pNew_social_network_elem->pUser = User_Create(new_member);
    if (!pNew_social_network_elem->pUser) return FAILURE;
    pNew_social_network_elem->pNext = pSocial_network;
    pSocial_network = pNew_social_network_elem;
    if (!Network_addRelationship(new_member, member_invite))
    {
        pNew_social_network_elem = pSocial_network;
        pSocial_network = pSocial_network->pNext;
        User_Delete(pNew_social_network_elem->pUser);
        free(pNew_social_network_elem);
        return FAILURE;
    }
    return SUCCESS;
}
Result Network_addRelationship(char* member1, char* member2)
{
    if (!member1 || !member2) return FAILURE;
    PUser pMember1 = NULL;
    PUser pMember2 = NULL;
    social_network_elem current = pSocial_network;
    while (current)
    {
        if (strcmp(member1, User_getName(current->pUser)) == 0)//we found member 1
        {
            pMember1 = current->pUser;
        }
        if (strcmp(member2, User_getName(current->pUser)) == 0)//we found member 2
        {
            pMember2 = current->pUser;
        }
        current = current->pNext;
    }
    if (!pMember1 || !pMember2) return FAILURE;//one of the mambers not in the list
    if (!User_addFriend(pMember1, member2)) return FAILURE;//create relationship failed
    if (!User_addFriend(pMember2, member1))
    {
        User_removeFriend(pMember1, member2);
        return FAILURE;
    }
    return SUCCESS;
}
Result Network_removeRelationship(char* member1, char* member2)
{
    if (!member1 || !member2) return FAILURE;
    PUser pMember1 = NULL;
    PUser pMember2 = NULL;
    social_network_elem current = pSocial_network;
    while (current)
    {
        if (strcmp(member1, User_getName(current->pUser)) == 0)//we found member 1
        {
            pMember1 = current->pUser;
        }
        if (strcmp(member2, User_getName(current->pUser)) == 0)//we found member 2
        {
            pMember2 = current->pUser;
        }
        current = current->pNext;
    }
    if (!pMember1 || !pMember2) return FAILURE;//one of the mambers not in the list
    if (User_getFriendsNum(pMember1) <= 1 || User_getFriendsNum(pMember2) <= 1) return FAILURE;//num of friends is less than 2
    if (!User_removeFriend(pMember1, member2) || !User_removeFriend(pMember2, member1)) return FAILURE;//remove relationship failed
    return SUCCESS;
}
void Network_delete()
{
    social_network_elem current = pSocial_network;
    social_network_elem tmp= NULL;

    while (current)
    {
        tmp = current->pNext;
        User_Delete(current->pUser);
        free(current);
        current = tmp;
    }
}
```

I have errors in the call to free in the following functions:

Network_delete()

the other calls for free give no error.

furthermore, I use Valgrind in Unix environment for memory violation and debug and it seems like the mallocs create blocks in a different size to the types it contains.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "breakpoint". Please include the exact error message verbatim. (Copy and paste, please, not as an image.) Also, typedef'ing pointer types is considered by many to be bad style, because it is hard to read and can hide otherwise obvious bugs.

Comment: @user3121023 few min before you posted it I found that and fixed it. It solved my problems. playing with pointers require delicate care. Thanks for the help!!!